# Inferring parameter types in a generic class which are nested generic types of provided arguments

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have a class:

```
class MyClass<F extends Field, G extends OtherClass<F>> {
     ...
}
```

The problem is that, given information about the class `G`, I can easily infer the type `F`. However, instantiation right now requires me to do this:

```
new MyClass<ConcreteField, ConcreteOtherClass>();
```

To use the `<>` syntax, I used a small hack and added a constructor:

```
public MyClass(Class<G> gClass) {}
```

This allows me to use the diamond syntax, as the compiler is now able to easily infer the types:

```
new MyClass<>(ConcreteOtherClass.class);
```

Is there a way for me to require to only pass in the type `G` (as in the 'constructor hack') without using a constructor as mentioned?

Comment: Just so you know, the compiler infers the type, not the JVM.

Comment: The compiler -in most cases- could infer types for static methods even for Java 5, so that might be an option. Create a "factory" method to create instances of the proper object.

Comment: You shouldn't need such a hack to be able to use the `<>` operator - the compiler can infer the type easily from the reference type. What is the reference type we're talking about here? I mean where do you need to instantiate the type this way using the `<>` operator?

Comment: Yeah.. edited the question to say 'compiler' instead of the JVM.

Comment: @mystarrocks I don't need a reference variable. It works something like, `new MyClass<>().addSpec(..).addSpec(..).buildSpecList()`. So, the reference variable which I need in this case is simply `List<Spec>`.

Comment: Maybe use a static factory method on `MyClass`?

Comment: It vaguely appears that you are using the builder pattern to chain various method calls on `MyClass` instance and finally return a fully built `MyClass` instance. Is this correct? A bit more context would help - like the methods you're wanting to chain and so on. As such, `new MyClass<>().anySimpleMethod()` will work - the compiler will interpret the type of `F` to be `Field` and `G` to be `OtherClass<Field>`, that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thought about it a while but I didn’t find any simple generic construct allowing this kind of type inference.

Regarding the specialized dummy-argument constructor it’s worth noting that you don’t need to pass an actual `Class` instance; any type which allows inferring `G`, including `G` itself would work. E.g., if you change the `public MyClass(Class<G> gClass) {}` constructor to `public MyClass(G ignored) {}` you can instantiate the class using `new MyClass<>((ConcreteOtherClass)null)`.

You can also hide the `null` reference and write the instantiation without any type cast by adding a method providing the dummy value:

```
class MyClass<F extends Field, G extends OtherClass<F>> {

    public MyClass() {}
    public MyClass(G dummy) {}

    public static <T> T infer() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate the class with full type inference like this:

```
new MyClass<>(MyClass.<ConcreteOtherClass>infer())
```

---

Since you asked for a solution *without* a specialized constructor I will add such a solution. But you will see that this is not really improving maintainability of your code:

```
interface Instantiator<T extends OtherClass<?>> extends Runnable {
    default <M extends MyClass<?,? extends T>> M get(Supplier<? extends M> s) {
        return s.get();
    }
    static <X extends OtherClass<?>> Instantiator<X> i() {
        return ()->{};
    }
}
```

Using this helper class you can instantiate `MyClass` with type inference using the default constructor as

```
Instantiator.<ConcreteOtherClass>i().get(MyClass::new)
```

Note that this two-step instantiation would work with ordinary types as well, but making this `Instantiator` a functional interface and instantiating it via lambda expression is the only way to make it a type safe singleton, i.e. as of current Oracle’s implementation, there will be only one instance of `Instantiator` within the runtime, regardless of how you parametrize it, as it is stateless (and does exist only to make the compiler happy…).

Comment: True that I only need to pass any type that allows the compiler to guess it, in my context Class<G> seemed more semantically correct (the class is a criteria generator for a type, so the constructor said create a generator for this type, hence Class). Although I won't be using this, this is AWESOME! (hence marking it as an answer) I really like the solution, but I have never seen something like this before `return ()->{}`. What does that do?

Comment: `()->{}` is a [lambda expression](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1-2080972.html). Basically, it creates an instance of our `interface` using the lambda’s code for the single `abstract` method, so here it implements the `run` method which `Instantiator` inherited from `Runnable` as no-op (the specified `{}`). One nice property of these lambda expressions is that the implementation might reuse the created instance on subsequent calls (and Oracle’s JRE does that).

Comment: So here there will be only one instance of `Instantiator`, even if we call `Instantiator.i()` with different type arguments for `X` as the actual type of `X` is irrelevant at runtime (that’s the thing which doesn’t work with ordinary generic classes). The code would be even better if we made the `get` method `abstract` and implemented it via lambda expression (then we didn’t need extend `Runnable`) but unfortunately it doesn’t work due to `get`’s `<M>` type parameter. So I made this workaround with the obsolete `run` method to be able to combine the concrete `get` method with lambda expression